# Setting navigable limits PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a `QGraphicScene` with a `pixmap` on it. I'm able to move around the `pixmap` by handling the `keyPressEvent`, the idea is that I want to limit the navigable area, so the image will not leave the visible area.
I think there is an option to create a function, and to call depending on a bool value.
BUT is there an easy way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the [QGraphicScene](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgraphicsscene.html) rectangle with one of the following:

```
QGraphicsScene.setSceneRect (self, QRectF rect)
QGraphicsScene.setSceneRect (self, float x, float y, float w, float h)
```

According the official Qt docs for the property [sceneRect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRect-prop):

> This property holds the scene rectangle; the bounding rectangle of the scene.
>
> The scene rectangle defines the extent of the scene. It is primarily used by QGraphicsView to determine the view's default scrollable area, and by QGraphicsScene to manage item indexing.
>
> **If unset, or if set to a null QRectF, sceneRect() will return the largest bounding rect of all items on the scene since the scene was created (i.e., a rectangle that grows when items are added to or moved in the scene, but never shrinks).**

Comment: If you move the image up or to the left, you have this problem too? Or is only a down and right thing?